# Error using win32com & pttsx3 for Python Voice Recognition

Tags: python-3.x

'''

Please help me out at this stage.i want to do this program with win32com & pyttsx 3. tried both but not working . Below is my code please check and help.

I want program to answer me back as as per defined answers.

Program is working fine and replying as a text but i am not getting any response by voice..

'''

```
# audio.py   File

import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyglet
from commands import Commander
import subprocess
import win32com.client as wincl
import wave
import pyttsx3

running =  True   #ss

def say(text):
    speak = wincl("SAPI.SpVoice")
    speak.Speak('say ' + text, shell=True)

def play_audio(filename):
    chunk = 1024
    wf = wave.open(filename, 'rb')
    pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = pa.open(
        format=pa.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
        channels = wf.getnchannels(),
        rate = wf.getframerate(),
        output = True
    )

    data_stream = wf.readframes(chunk)

    while data_stream:
        stream.write(data_stream)
        data_stream = wf.readframes(chunk)

    stream.close()
    pa.terminate()

play_audio("./audio/after.wav")

# Upper part is to play sound using pyaudio

r = sr.Recognizer()

cmd = Commander()  #

def initSpeech():
    print("Listening.....")
    play_audio("./audio/before.wav")

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Say Something")
        audio = r.listen(source)

    play_audio("./audio/before.wav")

    command = ""

    try:
        command = r.recognize_google(audio)

    except:
        print("Couldn't understand you bro. ")

    print("Your Command: ")
    print(command)
    if command == "quit":
        running = False  #
    #echo('You Said: ' + command)

    cmd.discover(command)  #

    #speak.Speak('You Said: ' + command)   -------> no comment

while running == True:
    initSpeech()

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# commands.py   File

import subprocess
import os

class Commander:
    def __init__(self):
        self.confirm = ["yes", "affirmative", "si", "sure", "do it", "yeah", "confirm"]
        self.cancel = ["no", "negative", "negative soldier", "don't", "wait", "cancel"]

    def discover(self, text):
        if "what" in text and "your name" in text:
            if "my" in text:
                self.respond("You haven't told your name yet")
            self.respond("My name is python commander. How are you")

    def respond(self, response):
        print(response)
        speak.Speak('say ' + response, shell=True)  # This Speak is 
from pywin32
```

Comment: Please check  if i have any error in def say(text)  in audio.py file and def respond in commands.py file

Comment: Here is the link of repl.it     https://repl.it/@thekaranjit/voicerecognisation